# Views node author relationships with profile2 owner

Tags: views, users

I have a multi user site, with Profile2 enabled. And I've set up a views block which is only displayed on the Profile2 page, and is *supposed* to list content/nodes authored by the Profile2 page owner.

Now I've made a similar block for the user-page, which works perfectly, using the Content:Author relationship and a Content:Author UID(providing ID from URL as the default value) contextual filer.

But I just can't figure out which relationship(s) and contextual filter to use for the Profile2 page. Now I'm completely lost and googly eyed from trying random combinations.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it just not possible to filter the Author ID from the Profile ID(i.e does https://drupal.org/node/1834920 have something to do with my issue?)? Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get around this by setting up relationships with Content:Author and (author)User:Profiles. Then setting up a Contextual Filter of Content:Author UID, with Raw Data from URL, using Path Component 2, as the Default Value.